# How to get ALL the results from both tables A and B? (outer join doesn't exist?)

Tags: mysql, sql

Easiest way to explain is with an example:

```
mysql> select * from table_a left join table_b on col_a=col_b;
+-------+-------+
| col_a | col_b |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |  NULL |
|     2 |  NULL |
|     3 |     3 |
|     4 |     4 |
+-------+-------+

mysql> select * from table_a right join table_b on col_a=col_b;
+-------+-------+
| col_a | col_b |
+-------+-------+
|     3 |     3 |
|     4 |     4 |
|  NULL |     5 |
|  NULL |     6 |
+-------+-------+
```

But how do I get this?

```
mysql> select * from table_a ???? table_b on col_a=col_b;
+-------+-------+
| col_a | col_b |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |  NULL |
|     2 |  NULL |
|     3 |     3 |
|     4 |     4 |
|  NULL |     5 |
|  NULL |     6 |
+-------+-------+
```

---

Structure for @Abe:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_a` (
  `col_a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col_a`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `table_a` (`col_a`) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_b` (
  `col_b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col_b`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `table_b` (`col_b`) VALUES
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6);
```

Comment: Can we see what the source tables look like?

Comment: @Abe: I'm sure you can piece it together from those queries. `table_a` has 1 column `col_a` with values 1-4, likewise, table_b has values 3-6

Comment: You are correct @Mark I can.  I can also figure out source code with no comments whatsoever.  Doesn't mean I like to ;)

Comment: @Abe: Fair point... but it should be pretty simple in this case :)

Comment: yeah I agree that is pretty simple.

Answer (score 5):

Since there is no `FULL OUTER JOIN` option in MySQL I think you are limited to using a `UNION`:

```
select * from table_a left join table_b on col_a=col_b
UNION 
select * from table_a right join table_b on col_a=col_b
```

Answer (score 3):

This article provides several ways  of simulating a full outer join with MySQL.

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

hope this helps.